# unable to click on hidden item with many approaches in selenium,

Tags: jquery, python, selenium

this is site i try to get data from : http://www.flypeach.com/pc/en

however, when trying to choose a "FROM" location, I could only click to show location options form with codes :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.flypeach.com/pc/en")
inputFrom = driver.find_element_by_id("inputFrom")
inputFrom.click()
```

but failed to select any locations in the form with many approaches..such as 
`ActionChains` or `execute_script`,   anyone can help ??

the below are attempted codes :

```
 TPE = driver.find_element_by_id("TPE")
    ActionChains(driver).click(TPE).perform()
```

or

```
TPE = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='TPE']/a")
TPE.click()
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style = {};", TPE)
```

Comment: Add your attempted code also

Comment: TPE = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='TPE']/a")

Comment: TPE = driver.find_element_by_id("TPE") ActionChains(driver).click(TPE).perform() or
TPE = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='TPE']/a") TPE.click() or
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style = {};", TPE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to click on the From element, then you have select the element from the new pop-up 'dialogFrom'

here's the script:

```
WebElement locationElm = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='inputFrom']"));
        locationElm.click();

        WebElement fromElm = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dialogFrom']//*[@id='KIX']/a"));
        formElm.click();
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you sososososo  much !!  Nitish!!

Comment: by the way Nitish ,in the html source code, i can't find any tag with id = 'dialogFrom' , how did you know it is there ?

Comment: its there once you select the new pop-up, you ll be able to see  the tag

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this website source code, there is a full list of "from" and "to" airports.

For example:

```
<div id="fromDialogTemplate" style="display:none;">
<div class="airportList dialog_3columns">
    <div class="col_1 c1">
        <div class="country">Japan</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="KIX"><a href="KIX">Osaka, Kansai (KIX) </a></li>
            <li id="CTS"><a href="CTS">Sapporo, ShinChitose (CTS) </a></li>
            <li id="SDJ"><a href="SDJ">Sendai, Sendai (SDJ) </a></li>
            <li id="NRT"><a href="NRT">Tokyo, Narita (NRT) </a></li>
            <li id="HND"><a href="HND">Tokyo, Haneda (HND) </a></li>
            <li id="MYJ"><a href="MYJ">Matsuyama, Matsuyama (MYJ) </a></li>
            <li id="FUK"><a href="FUK">Fukuoka, Fukuoka (FUK) </a></li>
            <li id="NGS"><a href="NGS">Nagasaki, Nagasaki (NGS) </a></li>
            <li id="KMI"><a href="KMI">Miyazaki, Miyazaki (KMI) </a></li>
            <li id="KOJ"><a href="KOJ">Kagoshima, Kagoshima (KOJ) </a></li>
            <li id="OKA"><a href="OKA">Okinawa, Naha (OKA) </a></li>
            <li id="ISG"><a href="ISG">Ishigaki, Ishigaki (ISG) </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col_1 c2">
        <div class="country">Korea</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="ICN"><a href="ICN">Seoul, Incheon (ICN) </a></li>
            <li id="PUS"><a href="PUS">Busan, Gimhae (PUS) </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="country">HongKong</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="HKG"><a href="HKG">HongKong, HongKong (HKG) </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="country">Taiwan</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="TPE"><a href="TPE">Taipei, Taoyuan (TPE) </a></li>
            <li id="KHH"><a href="KHH">Kaohsiung, Kaohsiung (KHH) </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="country">China</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="PVG"><a href="PVG">Shanghai, Pudong (PVG) </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col_1 c3">
        <div class="country">Thailand</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="BKK"><a href="BKK">Bangkok, Suvarnabhumi (BKK) </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi , i did check source code and its from or to airport list, but with unable to select anyone of them ......i even try to locate them with XPATH  HELPER on chrome, but somehow one airport Xpath surprisingly show 3 identical airport name ..